# Javascript function not displaying values or writing them to textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Basically I am creating a simple function in javascript to check if a textbox value has changed from what it was originally and if so to warn the user the impact the change will have.  If the user clicks yes, do nothing, if they click no then I want to set the value of the textbox back to the original value it should be for them.

*EDIT*

Okay it seems I was mistaken as to the root of the problem.  It seems that the inpUsername which is a hidden input I have is blank from the beginning.  How do I set it correctly in the asp portion of the code so it takes the value of another textbox on the same control?

I currently have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="inpUsername" runat="server" value=
%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"txtUsername")%> />
```

This returns the error:  BC30456: 'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.  However if I add additional quotes around the value it outputs "/> to the screen

The txtUsername declaration as requested is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" Style="width:100%" 
onchange="checkForUsernameChange()"/>
```

Comment: Just a side note but `.value !== 0` is always true as `.value` returns a string not the number type `!== 0` implicitly tests for (so `!== "0"` or `!= 0`).

Comment: Have you checked the txtUsername/inpUsername are what you expect? if `document.getElementById("<%=inpUsername.ClientID%>").value` is empty so should be `inpUsername`, may also help to add the rendered js to your question.

Comment: yes inpUsername is null unfortunately, that is my issue.  How can I set it in the asp part to be equal to the value of txtUsername.value?  Anything I do seems to throw errors

Comment: Can you add the txtUsername declaration as well?

Comment: apologies, it has been added to the main description above now

Comment: Resolved it now after being an idiot for ages.  I just set the value of the hidden input in the vb file and went from there.  Apologies for wasting your time all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var txtUsername = document.getElementById("   <%=txtUsername.ClientID%>").value;
```

There's some spaces before the ID. I'm pretty sure you wanted :

```
var txtUsername = document.getElementById("<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>").value;
```

Or maybe the spaces were intended, in which case the `confirm` should also include those spaces.

Comment: There are no spaces in my code, that's just caused by the formatting to get the code on here, it was the first time I'd put code into a post.  For whatever reason I cannot seem to get the values from those textboxes to output and they definitely should not be blank

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle with that because we lack information to answer you. We could assume that the txtUsername is empty, which is different from the previous username ...

Comment: I have indeed been an idiot and never set the value of the hidden field so it was correctly blank.  I'm not sure why the other boxes weren't producing values until now though

Comment: My problem is that i'm essentially leaving inpUsername blank, how do I get the value from txtUsername into inpUsername at the start?  The current method below clearly isn't working

<input type="hidden" id="inpUsername" runat="server" value=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"txtUsername")%>/>

Comment: You are missing " for the value : <input type="hidden" id="inpUsername" runat="server" value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"txtUsername")%>" />

Comment: You should really put all the code that matters in your post, it's hard to understand the whole picture with simply bits of code.

Comment: It seems to take that as a literal string value though, so rather than equalling a value such as 'Nicholas' it is equal to '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"txtUsername")%>' ?

Apologies for the spaghetti code etc, I didn't think it was the source of the problem so didn't include it, I thought it was limited to the function itself